# Failed to connect to Postgres container to Go container

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to connect my Go container with my postgres-alpine container. But, I can not able to connect to connect it.

I am getting the following error

```
web_1  | [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=db  
         user=postgres database=go`: dial error (dial tcp 192.168.144.2:5432: connect: no route
         to host)
web_1  | 2023/09/05 09:26:10 Failed to connect to database: 
web_1  | failed to connect to `host=db user=postgres database=go`: dial error (dial tcp 
         192.168.144.2:5432: connect: no route to host)
```

I am using .air.toml to run my server.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   db : 
    image : postgres:alpine
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports :
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web : 
    build : .
    env_file : 
      - .env
    ports : 
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on : 
      - db 
    volumes : 
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command : air cmd/main.go -b 0.0.0.0

volumes:
  postgres-db:
```

My function to connect with my db:

```
func ConnectDb() {
dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=db user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/India",
    os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
)

db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
    Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
})

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Failed to connect to database: \n", err)
    os.Exit(2)
}

log.Println("connected")
db.Logger = logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info)

log.Println("running migrations")
db.AutoMigrate(&models.Facts{})

DB = Dbinstance{
    Db: db,
}
}
```

My .env file:

```
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_NAME=go
```

Comment: `connect: no route to host` suggests something with your docker networking rather than postgresql not being ready to accept connections.

Comment: I am not using any created networks. Whike running the docker-compose file it is creating it's own networks   ... "api-postgres-docker-go_default" my network name.

Comment: Try exec-ing a shell in both the db and web containers and assess the situation from there. What IP addresses and network routes do you see, and can you e.g. use "nc" to connect from one to to other?

Comment: Use `docker network inspect [container]` to check the network layout of containers.